# Laravel: insert a new key:value to collection in child array

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

Hi I have a collection of in which I want to insert a new key and value

here is my attempt

```
 $interpreters = $interpreters->map(function ($interpreter) use ($minimumPingValue) {

        $interpreter['opi_ping'] = $minimumPingValue;
    });
```

But it is not adding the new key value in collection.

it is giving the same results

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "Interpreters list.",
    "data": {
        "interpreters": [
            {
                "id": "6",
                "first_name": "Khizar",
                "display_picture": "https://d2bsp66iispep6.cloudfront.net/9/avatars/63178ac704787578f2ec773048584b3b.jpeg",
                "rating": 5
            },
            {
                "id": "25",
                "first_name": "AJ",
                "display_picture": null,
                "rating": 4
            },
            {
                "id": "26",
                "first_name": "Ejaz",
                "display_picture": null,
                "rating": null
            }
        ],
        "call_tracking_id": "CTF1ZPJY6BKs2KEpzgDsD5aa6733e2bab4"
    },
    "status_code": 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a closure with your map call and as such you should return the variable that you are altering, so for example:

```
$interpreters = $interpreters->map(function ($interpreter) use ($minimumPingValue) {
        $interpreter['opi_ping'] = $minimumPingValue;
        return $interpreter;
    });
```